# API throwing an error when calling DirectionsRenderer.setOptions before receiving results

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am encountering a very strange error with my project. I normally use the version flag "3", but today I started getting errors, and rolling back to "3.8" fixes the issue.

In the header of my routing file, I have a couple of variables like so:

```
var SERVICE = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
    SERVICE_OPTIONS = {
        "avoidTolls": false,
        "avoidHighways": false,
        "optimizeWaypoints": false,
        "provideRouteAlternatives": true,
        "unitSystem": google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC,
        "travelMode": google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
var RENDERER = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
    RENDERER_OPTIONS = {
        "draggable": true,
        "preserveViewport": false,
        "suppressMarkers": false,//true,
        "suppressPolylines": false,
        "suppressInfoWindows": true,
        "polylineOptions": {
            "strokeColor": "#9900ff",
            "strokeOpacity": 0.5,
            "strokeWeight": 4
        }
    };
```

And way down near the bottom I have a method to

```
function route(zoomToResults,mode) {
    RENDERER_OPTIONS.preserveViewport = !zoomToResults;
    RENDERER.setOptions(RENDERER_OPTIONS);  // error is thrown here
    /* more code, and then */
    SERVICE.route(SERVICE_OPTIONS,parseRouteResults);
};
```

I have not changed the code, I just noticed I get an error now when I try to use RENDERER.setOptions() before receiving the route results.  The error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'travelMode' of undefined`, and is not thrown in 3.8.

Is this a bug with Google's API or a change to the way they've implemented their code internally that does not account for this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer...

From now on, `DirectionsRenderer.setOptions()` must be invoked with a `DirectionsResult` added to your `DirectionsRendererOptions` literal.

This throws an error:

```
RENDERER.setDirections(results);
RENDERER.setOptions(RENDERER_OPTIONS);
```

This works:

```
RENDERER_OPTIONS.directions = results;
RENDERER.setOptions(RENDERER_OPTIONS);
```